# Bootstrap is Overlapping Flash

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site that has bootstrap. And a SWF file (of a game.) When i use the Full Screen option of the game. A bootstrap panel overlaps the game.

If you want to see what happens. Heres some images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSdv.jpg
Becomes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M46qa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by putting the overlapping panel before (on top of) the game panel